# How to build XMPP application using Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xmpp

can anyone help me to undertand how can I build XMPP appication using Monotouch? What library can I use? Are there some example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try to port one existing C# XMPP library [like this one](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) and try to make an iPhone library project with it then reference it on the iPhone App Project and try to work with it :)

Alex